# Loop function class name with jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I have to following code:

```
$( ".content.one" ).clone().appendTo( ".cat.one .details" );
$( ".content.two" ).clone().appendTo( ".cat.two .details" );
$( ".content.three" ).clone().appendTo( ".cat.three .details" );
```

I wanted to loop this like

```
var obj = {
one: 'one',
two: 'two',
three: 'three'
};
$.each(obj, function (index, value) {
  $( ".content.(value)" ).clone().appendTo( ".cat.(value) .details" );
});
```

But I can't find out how to use the "value" inside the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var obj = {one: 'one',two: 'two',three: 'three'};

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  $(`.content.${value}`).clone().appendTo(`.cat.${value} .details`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content one">One</div>
<div class="content two">Two</div>
<div class="content three">Three</div>

<br/>
<div class="cat one"><div class="details"></div></div>
<div class="cat two"><div class="details"></div></div>
<div class="cat three"><div class="details"></div></div>
```

**Note**: `obj` is an **object** and as per [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), callback will be passed `key` and `value` as arguments rather than `index` and `value`.

Comment: Yes perfect. But there is one problem. The background of my code is, I want to copy content elements in categories. Content can also have 2 or more categories, so can appear in different categories. But now if one has 2 or more categories (one, two, three) it appears double. See the full codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmvzgY - see in my example, "Content 2a, 1e" appears 2x in Category 2

Comment: It is happening because, during 1st iteration for `one`, element with both `one` and `two` classes has been copied inside `category`. Now, when you run it for `two`, there are 2 elements matching the search criteria. You can update the selection to `$(`.hidden .content.${value}`)` to avoid the duplicate copies. For reference - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYybaj

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given below.

```js
$(".content ." + value).clone().appendTo(".cat ." + value + " .details");
```

If the it dosen't help request to share entire code.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunalety it is not working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwEBaR - I am trying to categorized content-divs. The codepen should it make a bit clearer

Comment: sorry. the issue is with the spaces in the script. Check the working codepen script https://codepen.io/nitigna09/pen/QRbKLK